# Does a bike helmet without chin straps make any sense?

Tags: safety, helmets

Wouldn't any major impact make it fly off the head and not protect you.

Comment: Exactly. It is similar to all safety gear that are not apply properly.

Comment: A bike (or football or hockey or polo) helmet without a chin strap or some other equivalent means to secure it to the head is worthless (except perhaps to keep the sun off you head).

Comment: Are you asking whether a helmet could me made that doesn't use straps, or whether a typical helmet with straps serves any purpose if the straps are not done up? There are a few motorbike helmets that are two piece designs with a pivot instead of straps, and those seem to work quite well. Something similar might be possible with a bike helmet, but ventilation, weight and cost make it unlikely I think.

Comment: There are few if any helmets that go down far enough to encase the head like a motorbike helmet.  Some downhill/full face ones might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  And no.  It makes some sense in that a helmet should fit snug enough to stay on on its own.  The chin strap's job it to keep the helmet on your head after the initial impact.  Were one to have some condition (a skin condition, stitches on the face or neck, etc) where the chin strap was extremely detrimental, one would be somewhat safer riding with a helmet simply missing the chin strap, than with no helmet at all.

However, barring some obvious condition, or a radical helmet design that doesn't require a strap to stay on after impact, a helmet without a chin strap makes no sense.

Comment: It would be quite easy for an unstrapped helmet to fly off in, say, a "head over" accident due to striking something or braking too hard with the front wheel.  In such a case the helmet would be dislodged before the head struck the ground.

Comment: Well, the over the neck adjustement, at the back of the head, can get tight, and seems like it could still make the helmet effective in many scenarios.

Comment: All of my helmets will stay on, without the chin strap, while I "bang head" like a 80's metal freak.  They should fit and stay on as well as a ball cap.  If your helmet doesn't, then it doesn't fit properly and you should get a different helmet.